# Picture Button with Text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, button

I've recently started learning VB.Net in Visual Studio 2010 for a side project, but I've become completely stuck.
All I want to do is simply draw a picture, then draw text on top of it.

This is the code that I have so far...

```
Dim allFolders As String() = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Project\Test")
For Each item As String In allFolders
        Dim newButton As New Button
        newButton.Name = item
        newButton.Width = folderW
        newButton.Width = folderH
        newButton.Left = folderX
        newButton.Top = folderY
        newButton.Image = My.Resources.Resources.grBtn
        newButton.Text = newButton.Name.Remove(0, 17)
        Me.Controls.Add(newButton)
        AddHandler newButton.Click, AddressOf openMyFolder
        folderX += folderXS
Next
```

If I set "Dim newButton As New Button" then it completely ignores the image and draws just the standard button... if I set "Dim newButton As New PictureBox" then it completely ignores the Text and only draws the image...

Surely there's some way that I can have both a picture and text?

Thank you for your time!

Thank you LarsTech! Anyone searching for a similar problem, the code I'm using is:

```
        Dim newButton As New Button
        newButton.Name = item
        newButton.Width = folderW
        newButton.Height = folderH
        newButton.Left = folderX
        newButton.Top = folderY
        newButton.Image = My.Resources.Resources.<Your Image Resource>
        newButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        newButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
        newButton.Text = newButton.Name.Remove(0, 17)
        Me.Controls.Add(newButton)
        AddHandler newButton.Click, AddressOf openMyFolder
        folderX += folderXS
```

Which will create nice, dynamic picture buttons with no boarder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't duplicate your issue entirely, but you aren't setting the Height property (you have Width twice).

Consider adding the following properties to show the image properly:

```
newButton.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
newButton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
newButton.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText
```

Comment: Well now I just feel silly... Yes, the lack of Height was causing the issue. As soon as I changed Width to Height on the folderH line it worked straight away, but had an ugly boarder (which I've managed to remove). Thank you!